# What is structured data postMetadataJSON in Blogger/Blogspot?

Tags: json, data-structures, metadata, blogger, google-search-console

I noticed that these codes have been added to HTML (Blogger/Blogspot). I don't know what it is. Is it necessary for blog, or do I need to delete?.

This is the code that is added:

```html
b:include data='post' name='postMetadataJSON'/>
            </b:includable>

<b:includable id='postMetadataJSONImage'>
  &quot;image&quot;: {
    &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;ImageObject&quot;,
    <b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable'>
    &quot;url&quot;: &quot;<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 1200, &quot;1200:630&quot;)'/>&quot;,
    &quot;height&quot;: 630,
    &quot;width&quot;: 1200
    <b:else/>
    &quot;url&quot;: &quot;https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ULB6iBuCeTVvSjjjU1A-O8e9ZpVba6uvyhtiWRti_rBAs9yMYOFBujxriJRZ-A=w1200&quot;,
    &quot;height&quot;: 348,
    &quot;width&quot;: 1200
    </b:if>
  },
</b:includable>
            <b:includable id='postMetadataJSONPublisher'>
 &quot;publisher&quot;: {
    &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;Organization&quot;,
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Blogger&quot;,
    &quot;logo&quot;: {
      &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;ImageObject&quot;,
      &quot;url&quot;: &quot;https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ULB6iBuCeTVvSjjjU1A-O8e9ZpVba6uvyhtiWRti_rBAs9yMYOFBujxriJRZ-A=h60&quot;,
      &quot;width&quot;: 206,
      &quot;height&quot;: 60
    }
  },
</b:includable>
```

If necessary for blog, there appears to be a problem.

```html
<b:includable id='postMetadataJSON'>

---- Why aren't codes here? -------

</b:includable>
```

thank you for your help

Bugra

Answer (score 0):

By this includables Blogger trying to add Schema objects in JSON-LD format for main post image and blog publisher (see Examples on [schema.org](https://schema.org/ImageObject)).

Answer (score 0):

This schema is inserted automatically by Blogger. It is critical for the SEO of your blog. Keep it, unless you want your blog to not be easily crawlable/readable by Google and other bots.